# Blender scripting all_objects not looping through all objects

Tags: python, scripting, blender

while working on a script I stumbled across this funny issue, if someone can help me understand this bizarre behaviour, I would be very please.

Context

I have one collection with 4 assets
I want to loop through all the assets and render each one of them in a separate file

My script looks like this

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if bpy.data.objects[obj.name].type == "MESH":
            bpy.data.objects[obj.name].hide_render = True
count = 0
collection1 = bpy.data.collections["Category1"]
for obj1 in collection1.all_objects:     
        obj1.hide_render = False
        Render_Scene(str(count))
        obj1.hide_render = True
        count += 1
```

and the output (wrong) is:

```
0.png
1.png
```

what's funny is that if I change the body of the loop with this:

```
for obj1 in collection1.all_objects:
        print(obj1.name)
```

the output is correct:

```
Cube
Icosphere
Cone
Cylinder
```

any suggestions?
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem (blender octane 2.93.2)
To me it looks like a Blender bug.
The code that doesn't work (there are 20 objects in the collection, that code
affect only 2 or 3 objects):

```
for obj in get_all_from_collection(name):          
    sel_by_name(name)
    obj.hide_render = (random.choice([True, False]))
```

however this will print all objects in the collection:

```
for obj in get_all_from_collection(name):
    print("hiding/showing object " + obj.name)
```

The workaround that worked for me was to iterate over object names, not the collection. I renamed all objects to "Puzzle-xxx" and run that code successfully:

```
for index in range(1,20):
    name = "Puzzle-" + str(index)     
    print("hiding/showing object " + name)
    # move to 'tmp' collection
    if random.choice([True, False]) == True:        
        bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection(collection_index=6)
```

(I changed my strategy and I'm moving to a hidden collection instead of disabling render but that doesn't matter)
It's a dirty workaround but it worked for me.

Comment: In the same veine :     `objs = bpy.data.objects` does not work for me, 
    `objs = bpy.data.collections[0].all_objects` works. shouldn't `bpy.data.objects` return all objects in the scene ?